# Setting OnClickListener in Profile Fragment.java but it says unreacheable

Tags: java, android, mobile

Hello i'm trying to add profile picture edit option in profile page of my application but whenever i write onclick listener gives me error below i don't know what to do can someone please help me ? checked id of button and else everything is correct

```
package com.example.stepapp.ui.profile;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.stepapp.R;


import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button ImCh;
    CircleImageView profile_image;
    private Button user;

    private TextView Username;
    private final int GALLERY_REQ_CODE=1000;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        ImCh =(Button) root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        user=(Button) root.findViewById(R.id.EditName);
        profile_image =root.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        Username = root.findViewById(R.id.Username);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "testing the button " +String.valueOf(ImCh.getId()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return root;


        ImCh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
               iGallery.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               startActivityForResult(iGallery,GALLERY_REQ_CODE);
            }
        });

        user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Username.setText("");
            }
        });


    return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(resultCode==GALLERY_REQ_CODE){
                profile_image.setImageURI(data.getData() );
           }
        }
    }
}
```

i tried every solution but setOnClickListener of button raising error i couldn't find any other solution

Comment: `return root` is the problem. You are returning from the function here and whatever follows cannot be reached. I think you can just delete this line because you return the root at the end.